# How should I report a Foreign Financial Account that contains more than one currency on TurboTax?

Tags: united-states, currency, international, turbotax

I use Turbotax to prepare my taxes in the United States. How should I report a Foreign Financial Account that contains more than one currency on TurboTax? All currencies are in the same account number. Should I create 1 entry for each currency, or only 1 entry for all currencies (which could be many currencies, e.g. a few dozens)?

[image]

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/pNtmFr
- https://redd.it/fg3f8f

Comment: You're probably better off contacting TurboTax about this.

Comment: @Kat that's not incompatible with making the information publicly available here.